# Expo build Error: Build failed: Gradle build failed with unknown error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, eas

I am using `expo eas cli` to build my expo app for android. I am getting the following error

```
     Running 'gradlew :app:bundleRelease' in /home/expo/workingdir/build/android
      Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0.1-all.zip
     10
    %.
    20%.
    30%.
    40%.
    50%.
    60%
    70%.
    80%.
    90%.
    100%
    Welcome to Gradle 8.0.1!
    Here are the highlights of this release:
     - Improvements to the Kotlin DSL
     - Fine-grained parallelism from the first build with configuration cache
     - Configurable Gradle user home cache cleanup
    For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/8.0.1/release-notes.html
    To honour the JVM settings for this build a single-use Daemon process will be forked.
    See https://docs.gradle.org/8.0.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:disabling_the_daemon.
    Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build
    > Task :gradle-plugin:pluginDescriptors
    > Task :gradle-plugin:processResources
    > Task :gradle-plugin:compileKotlin
    > Task :gradle-plugin:compileJava NO-SOURCE
    > Task :gradle-plugin:classes
    > Task :gradle-plugin:jar
    > Task :gradle-plugin:inspectClassesForKotlinIC
    FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.
    1: Task failed with an exception.
    -----------
    * Where:
    Build file '/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-font/android/build.gradle' line: 40
    * What went wrong:
    A problem occurred evaluating project ':expo-font'.
    >
    Could not set unknown property 'classifier' for task ':expo-font:androidSourcesJar' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.
    * Try:
    >
    Run with
    --stacktrace
    option to get the stack trace.
    >
    Run with
    --info
    or
    --debug
    option to get more log output.
    >
    Run with
    --scan
    to get full insights.
    ==============================================================================
    2:
    Task failed with an exception.
    -----------
    * What went wrong:
    A problem occurred configuring project ':expo'.
    >
    compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle
    * Try:
    >
    Run with
    --stacktrace
    option to get the stack trace.
    >
    Run with
    --info
    or --debug option to get more log output.
    > Run with
    --scan to get full insights.
    ==============================================================================
    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
    BUILD FAILED in 1m 51s
    5 actionable tasks: 5 executed
    Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.
```

I don't know about this error I tried googling about the issue but didn't found it I tried `chatgpt`
but it does not help.
If anyone knows how I can fix this, then I am really thankful.

my `app.json`

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "test",
    "slug": "test",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "package": "com.rajdewangon.constructionapp"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "95ad2c8a-0422-4560-ab33-b117b8f90b43"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

my `eas.json`

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 6.0.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "production": {}
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

I tried googling about the issue, I also promted it on chatgpt. But didn't found any solution.